# How to debug intern functional tests

Tags: intern, node-inspector

I am using node inspector to debug my intern functional test. How do i use debugger when inside a functional test?
If I have a functional test which looks like

```
'Sample Test' : function() {
            console.log("load row grid mesh test");
            return this.remote
            .setFindTimeout(5000)
            .setWindowSize(800, 500)
            .then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class, \'abcd\') and following-sibling::span[child::span[text() = \'App\']]]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue', 8000))
            .expand("App")
            .expand("Sample")
            .open("SampleApp.xlsx")
            .then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate( "//div[contains(@class, \'Cover\') and @style = \'display: none; top: 0px; left: 0px;\']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue', 8000))
            .findAllByClassName("abc")
              .getAttribute("style")
              .then( function(style) {
                  //I am able to put a debugger here without isssue
                  assert.isTrue(style.length < 32);
                  assert.notStrictEqual(style[0].indexOf("top: 0px;"), -1);
                  assert.notStrictEqual(style[25].indexOf("top: 480px;"), -1);
              }).end()
            debugger // I NEED TO PAUSE HERE
            .findByXpath('//div[@class = \'abc\']//span[text() = \'AppleSample\']')
              .moveMouseTo().end()
```

Not sure how to put a debugger. I am new to intern. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried running your client code in your browser of choice and using the browser's debugging tools?

Answer (score 0):

I am personally not familiar with intern, but assuming it provides Promise interface, you should be able to add a following code to trigger the debugger:

```
'Sample Test' : function() {
            console.log("load row grid mesh test");
            return this.remote
            .setFindTimeout(5000)
            .setWindowSize(800, 500)
            .then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class, \'abcd\') and following-sibling::span[child::span[text() = \'App\']]]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue', 8000))
            .expand("App")
            .expand("Sample")
            .open("SampleApp.xlsx")
            .then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate( "//div[contains(@class, \'Cover\') and @style = \'display: none; top: 0px; left: 0px;\']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue', 8000))
            .findAllByClassName("abc")
              .getAttribute("style")
              .then( function(style) {
                  //I am able to put a debugger here without isssue
                  assert.isTrue(style.length < 32);
                  assert.notStrictEqual(style[0].indexOf("top: 0px;"), -1);
                  assert.notStrictEqual(style[25].indexOf("top: 480px;"), -1);
              }).end()
            .then(function(node) {
              debugger; // PAUSE HERE
              return node; // forward the promise value 
            });
            .findByXpath('//div[@class = \'abc\']//span[text() = \'AppleSample\']')
              .moveMouseTo().end()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in general it's very hard to read the long script without break like the one you have.
And as you see, it's hard to debug also.

I would break it into variables, for example:

`var setConfig = this.remote
            .setFindTimeout(5000)
            .setWindowSize(800, 500);`

`var openSample = setConfig
            .then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class,\'abcd\') and following-sibling::span[child::span[text() = \'App\']]]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)
            .singleNodeValue', 8000))
            .expand("App")
            .expand("Sample")
            .open("SampleApp.xlsx");`

`var abc = openSample.then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate( "//div[contains(@class, \'Cover\') and @style = \'display: none; top: 0px; left: 0px;\']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue', 8000))
            .findAllByClassName("abc");`
...

It's still not the best way, but at least it looks clearer and help you easier in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself debugging by manually pausing the promise string most of the time.

I use `.sleep(10000)` right before the problem lineto pause the test and then manually exit crtl + c from the terminal and look over the state of the browser using firebug.

You can also set the reporter type when running the tests the 'console' reporter is pretty helpful, though a bit verbose, at finding errors in your code. More in the intern docs here https://theintern.github.io/intern/#reporter-overview